# using .on("click") in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3js to display a scatterplot. obj.dot_datas is a list which contains informations about each point.
I want points to change color when they are clicked (as well as their infos to be displayed). The informations are displayed as wanted, but I don't manage to change the color as "self" here is not linked to the circle.

```
circles = obj.svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(obj.dot_datas)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .on("click", function (d,i) {
        d3.select('#nodeInfos').html("name: "+d.label+"<br/> "+d.infos+");
        self.attr("fill", "orange");
    }
circles.attr("class", "point")
```

The "point" class give to each circle default attributes (cx, cy, r, fill and opacity)

How can I change the color of one circle when clicking it ? What sould I put instead of "self"?

Comment: should be able to use `this` inside there

Comment: in your code, self doesn't refer to anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know d3.js but I think it work the same way jQuery work.
Just replace `self` with `d3.select(this)`

Comment: It worked with "d3.select(this)" (but not with "this"). I must have done too much Python these days...